# What is the name of this Balanced Binary Tree?

Tags: avl-tree

BBTHMNN(h) = Balanced Binary Tree Have Minimum Number Of Nodes

BBTHMNN(h) = BBTHMNN(h-1) + BBTHMNN(h-2) + 1

Name of the balanced binary tree which satisfying the above formula. I have searched all over the internet but I couldn't found the name of the tree

Comment: I called mine "Fred".  I find they grow better if you talk to them.

Comment: Cows that have names produce 3% more milk.

Comment: Slightly more worrying is the fact that my binary tree is producing milk - is binary tree lactation considered normal?

Comment: isn't a a tree with a minimal set of nodes called a 'trunk'?  ;^)

Comment: Googling "binary tree lactation": 11k results. And I thought it was just me.

Comment: @Hamish - how does the cow know she has a "real" name and not "One Eighty-Three"?

Answer (score 1):

Kinda looks like the Fibonachi Series. Perhaps Fibonachi Tree?

Comment: Did you mis-spell Fibonacci to try and increase the challenge for the poster? ;)

Comment: So mark it as the answer and I'll get my precious points! :-)

Answer (score 1):

Knowing that you can not have searched the entire internet, at least not properly, I'll point you to the simplest resource that may help you find better search terms for your question: [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_tree#Types_of_binary_trees).

> A **perfect binary tree** is a *full
>   binary tree* in which all *leaves* are
>   at the same *depth* or same
>   *level*.[[3](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_tree#cite_note-2)] (This is ambiguously also called a *complete binary tree*.)
>
> A **complete binary tree** is a binary
>   tree in which every level, *except
>   possibly the last*, is completely
>   filled, and all nodes are as far left
>   as possible.[[4](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_tree#cite_note-3)]

Answer (score 1):

Your question isn't entirely clear to me, so I may be misunderstanding you here, but it sounds like you might be looking for an [AVL tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AVL_tree). These often show up in homework as they were the first tree data structures.